# C++ Pass an object into another object?

Tags: c++, class, logic

I don't know if I've missed something, but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work, and couldn't find the answer online.

Lets say I have a two classes, Class A, and Class B. (stored in separate files)

Class A has a function *setName()* that sets a variable within a Class A object.

Class B has a function *setOtherName()* that sets the value of a Class A object's name.

So I set *setOtherName()* up like so:

```
void setOtherName(ClassA& cla)
{
*cla.setName("foobar");
}
```

then my main script looks like so:

```
Class A burger;
Class B fries;
fries.setOtherName(*burger);
```

this does not work in my orignal script, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'ClassB::setOtherName(ClassA*&)
```

Any help is aprreciated! ( sorry for any confusion )

Actual code:
    main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "quests.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    quests GameQuests;
    player Player;
    GameQuests.quest1(Player);
    Player.main();

    return 0;
}
```

quests.cpp:

```
#include "quests.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void quests::quest1(player& charact){
    cout << "By the way, what was your name?" << endl;
    person1=4;
    system("pause");
    charact->setName();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: could you post the whole code :)

Comment: @KrysselTillada It's 4 files, and a lot of text.. are you sure?

Comment: Mind the M in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are the instructions on the linked page unclear?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley is this edit sufficient?

Comment: @SamTubb Check out my answer below.  I think that should get you going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of your `setOtherName` function should have the signature

```
void ClassB::setOtherName(ClassA& cla)
```

You need to specify that it is included in `ClassB`. Within your class definition of `ClassB`, make sure to include

```
void setOtherName(ClassA&);
```

Furthermore, since your variable `burger` is of type `ClassA` and not of type `ClassA*`, there is no need to dereference the variable upon passing it into the function.  Call it like

```
fries.setOtherName(burger);
```

You have also incorrectly dereferenced the variable `cla`.  That object is passed by reference, not pointer, so there is no need to dereference.

Comment: My original code is different from the example, I'll update with my actual code to see if that changes anything, because this still isn't working :/

Answer (score 2):

Why are you derefrencing burger?  You told the compiler to expect class A by reference, not by pointer.

Try:

```
fries.setOtherName(burger);
```

Also, get rid of the asterisk on setOtherName.

```
void setOtherName(ClassA & cla)
{
   cla.setName("foobar");
}
```

EDIT:
    Wrote a sample program of what I think you are trying to do below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Burger
{
public:
    Burger(){}
    void setName(std::string name){ m_name = name; }
    std::string getName(){ return m_name; }
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

class Fries
{
public:
    Fries(){}
    void setOtherName(Burger & burger){ burger.setName("FryBurger"); }
private:
};

int main()
{
    Burger A;
    Fries B;

    B.setOtherName(A);
    std::cout << A.getName() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to read about pointers and reference mate.
This is how your function should look like

```
void setOtherName(ClassA& cla)
{
  cla.setName("foobar");
}
```

There is no need to deference something that is not a pointer.

```
ClassA burger;
ClassB fries;
fries.setOtherName(burger);
```

again, you don't need to dereference burger since its not a pointer.

If burger was created like this:

```
ClassA* burger = new ClassA();
```

and the function

```
void setOtherName(ClassA& cla)
```

was taking a reference, you had to dereference burger

```
fries.setOtherName(*burger);
```